# Plotting marginal effects for Zero-inflation model coefficients in zeroinfl()

Tags: r, plot

I'm having trouble plotting a marginal effects plot of my zero-inflated negative binomial regression, specifically for the zero-inflation model.

I would like to create a plot, that visualizes the marginal effect of my variable in the zero-inflation model like the one below.

[image: Marginsplot for zero model]

My model is defined as:

```
model_1 <- zeroinfl(soaGEN ~
                      lguerrillad +
                      lstrikesd +
                      ldemond +
                      lriotsd +
                      ldmidtoward | lfpsimusa,
                    dist="negbin",
                    data_model)

summary(model_1)
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = soaGEN ~ lguerrillad + lstrikesd + ldemond + lriotsd + ldmidtoward | 
    lfpsimusa, data = data_model, dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.67403 -0.49186 -0.41840  0.06559  9.58756 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  3.93654    0.06873  57.273  < 2e-16 ***
lguerrillad  0.87534    0.10735   8.154 3.52e-16 ***
lstrikesd   -0.21427    0.11339  -1.890   0.0588 .  
ldemond     -0.01439    0.10429  -0.138   0.8903    
lriotsd     -0.07146    0.10447  -0.684   0.4939    
ldmidtoward  0.16672    0.10886   1.532   0.1256    
Log(theta)  -0.55302    0.06590  -8.392  < 2e-16 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.3032     0.1683   7.745 9.59e-15 ***
lfpsimusa    -0.6360     0.0630 -10.096  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 0.5752 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 19 
Log-likelihood: -5365 on 9 Df
```

However, I am unable to isolate the zero-inflation part of the model from the rest of the model when trying to visualize.

```
sjPlot::plot_model(model_1,type="pred",terms = "lfpsimusa")
```

[image: Output from above code]

Is there anyway to isolate or extract the zero-inflation model from the full model, and then plot this, or some other way to obtain the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) to compute and plot various quantities of interest for these models. (Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.)

The link above includes a Getting Started vignette, a plot vignette, and 20+ other vignettes, along with detailed documentation. The [Plotting Vignette](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/plot.html) in particular shows you how to customize the plots.

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(pscl)
data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")
mod <- zeroinfl(art ~ phd * ment + factor(fem) + factor(mar) | 1, data = bioChemists)

plot_predictions(mod, condition = "ment")
```

[image]

```r
plot_slopes(mod, variables = "ment", condition = "phd")
```

[image]

Comment: Using `type="zero"` in the `plot_predictions()` function will generate the zero-inflation probability graph.

Comment: 'Thank you very much! with the `type = "zero"` added it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using `ggpredict()` from the `ggeffects` package directly:

```r
library(pscl)
#> Classes and Methods for R developed in the
#> Political Science Computational Laboratory
#> Department of Political Science
#> Stanford University
#> Simon Jackman
#> hurdle and zeroinfl functions by Achim Zeileis
library(ggplot2)
data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")
fm_zinb <- zeroinfl(art ~ fem + mar + kid5 + phd | ment, data = bioChemists, dist = "negbin")

library(ggeffects)
g <- ggpredict(fm_zinb, terms="ment [all]", type="zi_prob")
plot(g) + 
  geom_rug(data=bioChemists, aes(x=ment), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution worked perfectly for my issue!

I was wondering if it's possible to add confidence intervals to this plot?

Comment: For some reason the confidence interval doesn't get produced.  You can use @Vincent's solution above, try: `marginaleffects::plot_predictions(fm_zinb, condition="ment", type="zero") + geom_rug(data=bioChemists, aes(x=ment), inherit.aes = FALSE)` for the model in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for giving those details @DaveArmstrong! Note that in the latest version of the package, there's a `rug` argument in `plot_predictions()`.